# How to create row in pandas dataframe from another row plus new data

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose that I have a pandas dataframe, `df1`:

```
import pandas as pd    
df1col = ['col1', 'col2']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df1col)
df1.loc[0] = 'a', 'b'
```

My goal is to create `df2` where the first two columns of `df2` are the same as those in `df1`. I use the names of the columns and append the column names of `col3` and `col4` on (is there a better way to do this?) and create the dataframe, `df2`:

```
df2col = df1col
df2col.append('col3')
df2col.append('col4')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df2col)
```

Now I simply want to add the first (and only) row of `df1` to the first row of `df2` AND I want to add two new entries (`c` and `d`) so that all the columns are filled. I've tried:

```
df2.loc[0] = df1.loc[0], 'c', 'd'
```

and

```
df2.loc[0] = [df1.loc[0], 'c', 'd']
```

But neither works. Any hints?

Comment: Do you want the data as well or df2 to have df1's column names?  and also what are the columns c and d filled with?

Comment: Both. I think that this code successfully creates `df2`, which has column names from `df1` plus two new column names. Now I want to create one row in `df2` that takes the values from row 0 of `df1` for the first two columns (`a` and then `b`). The third column will be `c` and the fourth `d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the list and then add 'c' and 'd' to it:

```
df2.loc[0] = df1.loc[0].tolist() + ['c', 'd']

>>> df2
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    a    b    c    d
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that df1.loc[0] is an object, not a pair of values outside of any structure.  You can fix it by extracting the values from df1.loc[0] and extending them with 'c' and 'd' as follows:

```
row1 = [val for val in df1.loc[0]]
row1.extend(['c', 'd'])
df2.loc[0] = row1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can copy a dataframe and to add a column to a dataframe works like a dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd    
df1col = ['col1', 'col2']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df1col)
df1.loc[0] = 'a', 'b'
df2 = df1.copy()
df2['col3'] = 'c'
df2['col4'] = 'd'
```